# How to open a changing file with wireshark?

Tags: networking, tcpdump, wireshark, packet, tshark

Given a `pcap` file that is being created in the background, e.g

```
   tshark -w out.pcap > /dev/null &
```

How can I open the changing file with wireshark

```
   wireshark -r out.pcap
```

Does nont work

Comment: Already asked here: http://superuser.com/questions/567831/follow-a-pcap-file-in-wireshark-like-tail-f

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I have trouble to compile the only [downloaded file](http://www.tobez.org/download/pcaptail-0.01.tar.gz): `pcaptail.c:144:22: error: ‘struct stat’ has no member named ‘st_birthtime’; did you mean ‘st_blksize’?`